# Is there a high level language that compiles to VBA?

Tags: vba, compilation, programming-languages

I would like to know if there is any language that compiles to VBA, like we have coffeescript for js, less for css...

If there is not, is there something that prevents us from achieving that? Would it be a bad idea?

I guess that would help people that are used to work with more modern languages to be a LOT more productive.

What would it take to do that ? Could we reuse the coffeescript grammar and parser, but hack into the steps that generate Javascript and generate VBA instead ? A subset of VBA would be just fine.

Comment: In the absence of a transpiler you can code your functions in the compiled language of your choice and build a dll which you can then access from VBA.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's always possible to compile from one Turing-complete language to any other. The result might not be fast, but it's generally fairly straightforward.

So, why was Coffeescript created *ex nihilo*, instead of using an existing language? Integration.

Suppose, for example, that we wanted to write JS in Haskell. You could easily implement a Haskell to JavaScript compiler. Now, suppose, writing in Haskell, you wanted to pop up a dialog box on a Web page. In JS, you'd write `alert("hello")`, but if your H2JS compiler is correct, there won't be any `alert` function, because Haskell functions don't have side-effects (perhaps the whole reason that you wanted to write in Haskell was so that you could have nice guarantees like that calling functions won't pop up dialog boxes).

There are many ways that your H2JS compiler could provide this functionality, but it's not necessarily obvious which one was chosen. You can't just read JavaScript documentation to learn how to do browser-y things; you also need to read the documentation for your H2JS compiler!

On the other hand, Coffeescript is similar enough to JS that it's pretty obvious how to pop up alerts, edit the DOM, etc., just from knowing how it's done in JS.

So, it's not hard to do in a slapdash way, but, if the source language is much different from VBA, it'll likely be tricky to do the VBA-specific things that make the project useful in the first place.

Comment: It's hard for me to see how the language that you to use to transpile one source to another is limiting the targeted language. I guess there is a misunderstanding. I'm talking about a language whose only goal is to be rewrited to VBA, like CoffeeScript is targeting Javascript. In the conception I have of source to source conversion, you go through parsing the first language into an AST, and emit the corresponding code in the other language. Am i wrong/incomplete ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm not saying that anything is technically impossible, just that making new CoffeeScript-like languages makes sense because respecting existing VBA integration features would be simpler and clearer.